# twitter-bootstrap 3 failing support btn btn-mini

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In twitter-bootstrap 2, there was a `btn btn-mini` class which I cannot find the equivalent for in Bootstrap 3. What is the equivalent in Bootstrap 3 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read the **[documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration)**, you will see that it has been replaced by `btn-xs`.

Comment: it is not only issue of size. the theme of button is different from `btn btn-xs`

Comment: The look of the button is ruled by the button class. You can take a look at the source here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/buttons.less. If you look at line 130 and line 134 you can see that the size is affected by btn-xs class. But the core is ruled by the .btn class at line 10 which has probably changed in bootstrap3 which you can override in your custom css.

Comment: To use it in b3, you need to write: btn btn-default btn-xs

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [migration guide](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/) which clearly summarize all the changes.